# flock fails on shared NFS for exclusive blocking locks from 2 different maschines

Tags: linux, nfs, locking

I use PHP flock() (which uses the system flock) on systems with shared file system via NFS.

The flock() fails when I use EXCLUSIVE, BLOCKING lock to access the same (shared) file on 2 servers. Of course, only one process should be able to obtain the (exclusive) lock, but the other should block in this case. But what I am seeing is that the flock() call returns immediately with an error.

If I do the same thing (start 2 programs to obtain EXCLUSIVE, BLOCKING lock) on 1 server, it works.

The question is: Should this work? Is it not recommended to use file locking via NFS in general? (The information that was given that it does not work at all often referred to outdated information). If this should work, what can I do to debug or solve this?

### Test setup

(I have used a [PHP script](https://github.com/sypets/flock_test/blob/master/flock_test_exclusive_blocking.php), but a simpler test setup can be done using the command line flock):

**System 1:**

```
flock -x lock.txt sleep 10
```

Result: lock is acquired

**System 2** (while System 1 has lock acquired):

```
flock -x lock.txt sleep 10
```

This returns immediately with

> flock: lock.txt: No locks available

### Diagnosis

```
strace flock -x lock.txt sleep 10

flock(3, LOCK_EX)                       = -1 ENOLCK (No locks available)
```

Add debugging information with `rpcdebug -m nfs  all` (on client)

This is the log for the failed flock attempt.

**/var/log/messages**

```
Feb  4 10:24:51 myclient kernel: NFS: initiated commit call
Feb  4 10:24:51 myclient kernel: NFS:  6791 nfs_commit_done (status 0)
Feb  4 10:24:51 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:40/916722366 fh_crc=0xa8927c2a ct=1 info=0x27e7f)
Feb  4 10:24:51 myclient kernel: NFS:       commit (0:40/916722366 1358@4096) OK
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: permission(0:41/872433655), mask=0x81, res=-10
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS call  access
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:41/872433655 fh_crc=0x9e46fe1a ct=2 info=0x27e7f)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS reply access: 0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: permission(0:41/872433655), mask=0x1, res=0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_lookup_revalidate(/lock.txt) is valid
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: permission(0:41/915542237), mask=0x10, res=0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: dentry_delete(/lock.txt, 40808cc)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: permission(0:41/872433655), mask=0x81, res=0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_lookup_revalidate(/lock.txt) is valid
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: revalidating (0:41/915542237)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS call  getattr
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS reply getattr: 0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:41/915542237 fh_crc=0x35293470 ct=1 info=0x27e7f)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs3_forget_cached_acls(0:41/915542237)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: (0:41/915542237) revalidation complete
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: dentry_delete(/lock.txt, 40808cc)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_weak_revalidate: inode 872433655 is valid
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: permission(0:41/872433655), mask=0x81, res=0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: revalidating (0:41/915542237)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS call  getattr
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS reply getattr: 0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:41/915542237 fh_crc=0x35293470 ct=1 info=0x27e7f)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: (0:41/915542237) revalidation complete
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_lookup_revalidate(/lock.txt) is valid
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS call  access
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:41/915542237 fh_crc=0x35293470 ct=1 info=0x27e7f)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS reply access: 0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: permission(0:41/915542237), mask=0x24, res=0
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: open file(/lock.txt)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: llseek file(/lock.txt, 0, 1)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: flock(/lock.txt, t=1, fl=82)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: flush(/lock.txt)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: release(/lock.txt)
Feb  4 10:24:59 myclient kernel: NFS: dentry_delete(/lock.txt, 40808cc)
```

### System

RHEL

```
uname -r
3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64



nfsstat –s


Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badclnt    badauth    xdrcall
0          0          0          0          0       

Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
588092     0          588092  

Client nfs v3:
null         getattr      setattr      lookup       access       readlink     
0         0% 350667   59% 0         0% 1714      0% 231693   39% 5         0% 
read         write        create       mkdir        symlink      mknod        
748       0% 2243      0% 0         0% 3         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
remove       rmdir        rename       link         readdir      readdirplus  
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 110       0% 
fsstat       fsinfo       pathconf     commit       
0         0% 10        0% 5         0% 889       0%
```

mount options:

rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,context=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=someip,mountvers=3,mountport=300,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=someip

---

I have searched about this topic. Some hits are [quite old](https://serverfault.com/questions/66919/file-locks-on-an-nfs), [did not get answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/642364/linux-nfs-server-refuses-blocking-locks) or refer to older versions of flock on linux which did not yet support shared locking.

For example on my system, man 2 flock gives the following information:

> In Linux kernels up to 2.6.11, flock() does not lock files over NFS (i.e., the scope of locks was limited to  the  local  system).   Instead,  one  could  use fcntl(2)  byte-range locking, which does work over NFS, given a sufficiently recent version of Linux and a server which supports locking.  Since Linux 2.6.12, NFS clients support flock() locks by emulating them as byte-range locks on the entire file.  This means that fcntl(2) and flock() locks do interact  with  one another  over NFS.  Since Linux 2.6.37, the kernel supports a compatibility mode that allows flock() locks (and also fcntl(2) byte region locks) to be treated as local; see the discussion of the local_lock option in nfs(5).

Comment: You're using NFSv3 You should try adding a rpcdebug option with `nlm` also as the lock management is handled by sidechannel protocols in NFSv3.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I did not have access to the server, only the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already lots of resources dealing with this problem.
In summary, you cannot use `flock` directly on NFS because of the reasons given in the man page.

Please see these links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218451/locking-nfs-files-in-php
- [File locks on an NFS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/66919/file-locks-on-an-nfs)

  - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#82521

Comment: The answers and quotes from the manpage are in part 10 years old. Most of the links you gave I already looked at. I asked the question to get a qualified answer about *current* versions of Linux, NFS + locking support.

Comment: Would you mind specifying exactly which versions are you using at the beginning of your question? If you did a proper research before you could share those resources too so we don't waste our time.

Comment: The kernel version is in the question. The nfs (client) version (v3) is also in the question. I did search for answers, wrote a test script, tested several scenarios, turned on debugging, checked the logs. I have a list of 10+ links? I can add them to the question. I did not do that before because it would bloat the question up even more. It is already quite long. I do not intend to waste anyone's time.